# Listview with checkbox, show the checked entries on another listview

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have a listview, which shows the picture, type/description of car and a checkbox. When the user now selected a car/s, I want to show them in another listview. When he unselected him from the CarListAdapter, it should also disappear from the new listview. Can I realize this with using the same Viewholder?

```
class CarListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    ArrayList<ItemsHolder> holderList;
    BitmapHelper bitmapHelper = BitmapHelper.getInstance();


    public CarListAdapter(ArrayList<ItemsHolder> holderList)
    {
        this.holderList = holderList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return holderList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

       final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(RentingDataActivity.this);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_renting_entry, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rowCarId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowCarId);

            holder.rowImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowImageView);
            holder.rowCarType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowCarType);
            holder.rowCarDescription = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rowCarDescription);
            holder.rowCheckbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);


            }


        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            //  holder.rowCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
      //      holder.rowCheckbox.setTag(R.id.rowCheckBox, position);
        }


   //     auto = holderList.get(position);
        final ItemsHolder ih = holderList.get(position);
        holder.rowImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapHelper.getBigImage(ih.getImagePath(), 248));
        holder.rowCarType.setText(ih.getCarType());
        holder.rowCarDescription.setText(ih.getCarDescription());
        // holder.rowCheckbox.setTag(ih);

        holder.rowCarId.setText(ih.getCarId());
        holder.rowCheckbox.setChecked(ih.isSelected());

        holder.rowCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);

              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), holder.rowCarType.getText().toString(),
              //  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                ih.setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());
            }
        });

       return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you describe it more clearly ? "When the user now selected a car/s, I want to show them in another listview" Where is this another listview ?

Comment: It's not implemented yet, because I'm thinking how I can filled, that only the selected one's will be showing.

Comment: You can reuse the same ViewHolder class in other list.

Comment: What is your Item Holder? Is it a class?

Comment: For this I would use a database with an int = (0 or 1) in it. From there you can select the cars with 0, or those with 1.

Comment: ItemsHolder is a class which inherit from my car database, with all cars im showing up in the CarListAdapter.

Comment: @EnderNicky, I want to solve this without saving in database.

Comment: You already have a database. It would be faster, and less memory taking

Answer (score 1):

I would add this as a comment but alas I haven't got enough points:

add to your adapter;

```
notifyDataSetChanged( );
```

This refreshes the list asynchronously.

Comment: now you have enough reps to comment as well @Matthew !!